# Discord.Net bot has weird delays when hosted on server

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I created a Discord bot using Discord.Net. When it's hosted locally on my laptop, it works just fine. However, when I uploaded it on Azure virtual machine with Ubuntu installed and managed to get it working under GNU Screen or tmux, it started showing weird behaviour. If the bot's commands aren't used for like 2-5 minutes, the next command posted in the server, bot doesn't react to it for 2 minutes, then posts "A task was canceled." error. After that it starts working just fine again. If multiple commands are sent during that delay, bot reacts with error response only to first one, and after it posts the error reason, it successfully processes other commands queued.

CommandHandler code:

```
    class CommandHandler
{

    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

    private CommandService _service;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _client = client;

        _service = new CommandService();

        _service.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;

    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage s)

    {
        var msg = s as SocketUserMessage;
        if (msg == null) return;

        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);

        int argPos = 0;
        if (msg.HasStringPrefix("!!", ref argPos))
        {
            var result = await _service.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos);

            if (!result.IsSuccess && result.Error != CommandError.UnknownCommand)
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class code:

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

    private CommandHandler _handler;

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "token removed for stackoverflow");

        await _client.StartAsync();

        _handler = new CommandHandler(_client);

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a consumption plan on azure?

Comment: Hmh, I'm not sure, it's not my server, and the owner is unsure how to check which plan they're running. Also, other bots on the same server work just fine, except another bot which is apparently written using Discord.Net as well, it has the same issue as mine.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you post the command you actually try to run. 
Considering the above code looks just fine for a discord bot.

Comment: I'm running the library with dotnet command, "dotnet Bot.dll".

Comment: I am talking about the discord command. Aka, if you have a `.help` command you run, after which you try to run the same command again, but it does not respond for 2-5 minutes. It most likely means there is something blocking there.

Comment: It doesn't respond even if I send only one command. Help command code:
`[Command("help")]
        public async Task help()
        {
            var a = new Discord.EmbedBuilder();
            a.WithTitle("Commands");
            a.WithDescription("help text here");
            a.WithColor(new Discord.Color(0, 170, 255));
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, a);
        }`